# Why can't I read static file in Jetty 8.1.9

Tags: configuration, jetty

In /opt/jetty/webapps, I have test.xml under directory w. I have this test.xml in contexts directory:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.eclipse.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/w</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase">/opt/java/webapps/w/</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>test.xml</Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
      <Set name="cacheControl">max-age=3600,public</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Why Can't I read `http://host/w/test.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, as you mention `test.xml` twice, and in two different directories.

Anyway, this is a basic example of setting up what you want, using the standard jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131.tar.gz available at [download.eclipse.org/jetty/](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/).

**The deployable context**

Create a file called `contexts/w.xml` with the following content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.eclipse.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/w</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/w/</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>test.xml</Item>
          <Item>index.html</Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
      <Set name="cacheControl">max-age=3600,public</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Notes:

- `${jetty.home}` points to whatever your `/path/to/jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131/` is
- This context points to a directory named `${jetty.home}/w/`, which is *not* in the webapps directory, this is intentional, as the webapps directory is for standalone Java Servlet or Java EE webapps, either in archive form, or in an exploded deployable form.  Since you are using `ContextHandler` and `ResourceHandler` your deployable does not meet these requirements.

**The content**

In the `${jetty.home}/w/` directory create a few files.

```
$ mkdir /path/to/jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131/w
$ echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>" > /path/to/jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131/w/index.html
```

**Testing it**

Start Jetty

```
$ cd /path/to/jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131
$ java -jar start.jar
```

Open up a browser and test it

```
http://localhost:8080/w/
```